# How to get flags passed to a make target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to get the flags passed to a make target. Currently I'm able to get the words passed to it but I would need the flags also. This is the current code:

```
ifeq (docker,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
  ARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))
  $(eval $(ARGS):;@:)
endif
.PHONY: docker
docker:
    @${DOCKER_FILE} $(ARGS)
```

I want to run something liek this: `make docker up -d`

Comment: You can't do that.  You have to do it as: `make docker ARGS='up -d'`.  Make is _not_ a general-purpose scripting language.  You don't have control over the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, your make invocation would treat `up` as a target and `-d` as a make parameter.  You can't tell make to interpret the parameters differently.   That being said, you can assign `up -d` to a variable and pass that in:

```
make docker ARGS="up -d"
```

```
.PHONY: docker
docker:
    @${DOCKER_FILE} $(ARGS)
```

And this would do what you want.   If you NEED to make the syntax similar to what you are describing for some reason, then you could create a wrapper script that would parse the arguments, and reformat them to a make specific target:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$1" == "docker" ] && make $1 ARGS="${@:2}"
```

```
bash> makedocker up -d
```

Comment: I think your answer is pretty near to what I want. Just to clarify. I can treat arguments with the snippet at the bottom of the make target, but I was facing problems with flags. I ended up using something similar on your answer. Thanks :)